# Crash between $2$ objects (human leg vs. car)

Tags: classical-mechanics, collision

Let's be $2$ bodies with two different structure. The mass of the first body (a human leg) is $14kg$ and the mass of the second body (a car) is $1000kg$. The point of the clash  between human leg and the car is the bumper of the car. We have two cases:

1. velocity of the first body (human leg) is $0kph$ and the velocity of the second body (car) is $40kph$.
2. velocity of the first body is $40kph$ and the velocity of the second body is $0kph$.

What does it happen after the bodies will crash? When the intrusion into the second body (bumper of the car) is bigger - when the second body have $0kph$ or when it have a velocity of $40kph$.

In my opinion the damage is greater for the second body (bumper of the car) when it have a velocity of $0kph$ and the first body (human leg) have a velocity of $40kph$.

I used some formula $v_{1}^{'}=2\frac{m_{1}v_{1}+m_{2}v_{2}}{m_{1}+m_{2}}-v_{1}$, but I do not obtain anything.

Thanks!

Comment: So, a car collides with a human... and you are interested in the damage on the car :)

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter whether the person crashes into the car, or the car crashes into the person (as long as the speed difference stays the same). Seen from an external observer with no absolute frame of reference, the crash will be identical in both cases.

Or said in another way: being knocked over by a car going at 40km/h hurts you as much as falling from 3 stories on the ground, with a final speed of 40km/h (in a purely kinetic point of view).